# System.DllNotFoundException: > gtk\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I've build a GUI on [Github](https://github.com/saigkill/PublicanCreators/blob/master/src/PublicanCreators/Program.cs).

After launching the built solution i've got:

> {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'Gtk.Application' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'GLib.GType' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException:
>   gtk\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   GLib.GType:g_type_init ()   at GLib.GType..cctor () [0x00192] in
>   <3683aafe72b14a2db70c1aa8c87dbafa>:0     --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---   at Gtk.Application..cctor () [0x00000] in
>   <97df079e817c4064808c8a386b3beb10>:0     --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---   at PublicanCreators.GladeApp..ctor (System.String[]
>   args) [0x00007] in
>   /home/sascha/RiderProjects/PublicanCreators/src/PublicanCreators/Program.cs:66
>   at PublicanCreators.GladeApp.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00002] in
>   /home/sascha/RiderProjects/PublicanCreators/src/PublicanCreators/Program.cs:60
>   }

Its available there:

- /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
- /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.5000.2
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.5000.2

gnome-sharp.dll.config says:

```
<configuration>
  <dllmap dll="libglib-2.0-0.dll" target="libglib-2.0.so.0"/>
  <dllmap dll="libgobject-2.0-0.dll" target="libgobject-2.0.so.0"/>
  <dllmap dll="libgthread-2.0-0.dll" target="libgthread-2.0.so.0"/>
  <dllmap dll="libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll" target="libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0"/>
  <dllmap dll="gnome-2" target="libgnome-2.so.0"/>
  <dllmap dll="gnomecanvas-2" target="libgnomecanvas-2.so.0"/>
  <dllmap dll="gnomeui-2" target="libgnomeui-2.so.0"/>
  <dllmap dll="gnomesharpglue-2" target="/usr/lib/cli/gnome-sharp-2.24/libgnomesharpglue-2.so"/>
</configuration>
```

And ldconfig says:

ldconfig -p |grep libgobject
libgobject-2.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
libgobject-2.0.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
libgobject-2.0.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so

Maybe anyone has an idea?

Comment: Check locations of dll.  The default location is usually the bin\debug or bin\release folder.   It looks like you are missing either debug or bin.  Normally you should add libraries using Add Existing Item and browse for the location where dlls are located.  The compiler will automatically copy the dll from source location to proper bin folder.

Comment: Thanks, that helped :-)